# GoogleMap in hidden div off center

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I use GoMap jQuery plugin for Google map. The div with the map is hidden by default. I almost figured how to display the map correctly, but somehow I'm unable to center the map after I reveal the div. I tried every solution I was able to find, right now I have the code below, which still doesn't work right. Anyone could help me with this? Thanks.

```
<h3><a class="showmap" href="#">Show map</a></h3>
<div id="map" style="height: 350px; width: 700px;"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
$("#map").goMap({
markers: [{  
        latitude: 49.676196, 
        longitude: 13.444927, 
        html: { 
            content: 'Marker description', 
            popup: true 
        } 
    }], 
    hideByClick: false,
    zoom: 12
}); 
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#map").hide();
});

$('.showmap').click(function(){
 $('#map').slideToggle('slow', function() {
  var center = $.goMap.map.getCenter();      
  google.maps.event.trigger($.goMap.map, 'resize');
  $.goMap.map.setCenter(center);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is almost perfect, but by default the map will pan to make the infoWindow visible, what will change the center.
You may disable the AutoPan:

```
$("#map").goMap({
markers: [{  
        latitude: 49.676196, 
        longitude: 13.444927, 
        html: { 
            content: 'Marker description', 
            popup: true ,
            disableAutoPan:true//<--
        } 
    }], 
    hideByClick: false,
    zoom: 12
}); 
});
```