# Adding a geocoded google map to div

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I've spent all day looking at the documentation and examples but I'm turning myself inside out. I was hoping I could be directed to the correct way to do this. I'm using jQuery.

The aim is to have a map that shows students where abouts the country is [that a story](http://www.abc.net.au/btn/story/s3619585.htm) is referring to. I have implemented it once using a [cut&paste solution](http://awardwinningfjords.com/2009/07/22/google-maps-with-jquery.html) but it doesn't work when toggling the div - to cut a long story short, I feel i need to redo it but am a bit out of my depth. I found [elsewhere on here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5984179/43465) the code for geocoding:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = $("#infopanel .map a.header").text();
map = $("#infopanel .map div");

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    } 
});
```

And this is the code for adding a map but notice I can't work out how to get the results of the geocoding into the center variable of mapOptions:

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(*geocoded-data*),
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false
   };

    new google.maps.Map(map,mapOptions);
```

Here is the slideToggle code with resize/center solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13734729/43465) but again, how do I get the geocoded data into setCenter:

```
$("#infopanel ul li > div").slideToggle("fast"); // hide the content
$("#infopanel a.header").click(function(e){ // toggle the content.
var hascontent = $(this).next("div");
if (hascontent.length == 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow", function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); // resize map
        map.setCenter(*geocoded-data*); // center map
        });
    }
});
```

And for context, here is the HTML that it will all sit in:

```
<li class="map"><a href="" class="header">Zimbabwe</a>
    <div style="width:220px;height:220px;"><a href="http://maps.google.com.au/maps?q=Zimbabwe&amp;z=3">Find Zimbabwe on Google Maps</a></div>
</li>
```

How do I connect the dots between those three?

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by using goMap plugin after reading this question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/10987802/43465). I'm still not sure what the answer is to the above question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really simple example that sets the [center of the map from a geocoded address](http://www.geocodezip.com/GMapsExampleV3b.html).

The key is this:

```
  if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
```

which sets the center of the map to the value returned if the geocode operation is successful.

Comment: My main problem was getting the info from the geocode results passed onto the other functions. I may not have had the right code to center a marker too but that wasn't the whole problem. As you can see on my comment I found a solution in the end.